# Proof of limit theorem by definition

Tags: real-analysis

I was trying to prove one of limit theorems by two ways..

I figured out to prove it by SCL but failed in using definition way..

If $\lim_{x\to p} f(x) = L$, $\lim_{x\to p} 1/f(x) = 1/L$ ($L$ is nonzero)

I tried taking $\epsilon = |L|/2$ but couldn't advance further...

I really appreciate it..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The limit of reciprocal is the reciprocal of the limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939852/the-limit-of-reciprocal-is-the-reciprocal-of-the-limit)

Comment: Totally yes! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You know you can make $|f(x)-L|$ small by making $|x-p|$ sufficiently small.

Try to rewrite $\left|\frac1{f(x)}-\frac1L\right|$ in terms of $|f(x)-L|$. (Think common denominator.)

You will also need to bound the denominator away from zero.